# Is it possible to group entries by checkbox?

Tags: entries, group

We're looking to output a list of entries and group them by their check box values. Here's what we've got so far:

```
{% for checkbox, entries in craft.entries.section('my_entries').find() | group('checkbox') %}
   {{ checkbox }}
{% endfor %}
```

This currently returns "Object of class Craft\MultiOptionsFieldData could not be converted to string".

Any ideas? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What Brad says, plus an example of grouping by selected checkbox:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('my_entries') %}

{# get all checkbox options #}
{% set options = entries.first().checkbox.options %}

{% for option in options %}
    <h2>{{ option }}</h2>
    <ul>
    {% for entry in entries if entry.checkbox.contains(option) %}
       <li>{{ entry.title }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `checkbox` is an instance of [MultiOptionsFieldData](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/fieldtypes/MultiOptionsFieldData), which behaves like an array of all of the possible checkbox options.

It doesn't have a `__toString()` method on it, which is why you're getting the error.

I assume what you want to be doing is grouping by a selected checkbox, no?

Comment: I expected to be able to do the a similar thing with categories, but think I'm running into the same thing: ```{% set entries = craft.entries.section('media').find() %}
{% set entriesByCat = entries|group('mediaCategory') %}
``` Can we just not use `.group` like this?

Comment: I meant `|group`, as in the filter :)

Comment: Added a related recipe: http://craftcookbook.net/recipes/330

Comment: It would be nice if `group` was aware of `Craft\ElementCriteriaModel`s, so you could do something like:```{% set entriesByCat = entries|group('myCategory.slug') %}```

Comment: Though maybe that's a better case for a `groupCriteria` filter or something...ok I'll stop adding comments now.

Comment: @paul, I just made a plugin to make this kind of grouping easier: https://github.com/timkelty/groupby-craft